# How do I toggle TNT off

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I toggle TNT explosions off?  I need to know because I want to play TNT Run by CraftedMovie Group.

Answer (score 12):

There's no way to turn TNT explosions off in vanilla Minecraft. The TNT Run video you're thinking of was recorded on a server with a plugin that turns off the explosions.

The server probably has something like the [WorldGuard Explosion Flags plugin](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-mods/worldguard-explosion-flags/) installed.

Comment: What about `/gamerule tntExplodes true`?

Comment: @RyanAmos That would work now! Game rules were first added in 2012 and that one didn’t exist yet in 2013 when this was written.

Comment: Hah! I totally missed the date

Answer (score 1):

You can use a repeating command block to kill TNT entities with a `Fuse` value below a certain point, since TNT will only explode when its `Fuse` value (decremented by 1 every tick) reaches zero.