# How do I install TNT Run or any other mini game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had trouble installing mods so I've been using Magic Launcher. I would like to play TNT Rn and other mini games, but I don't know how to get it to work. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119439/how-do-i-toggle-tnt-off

Answer (score 4):

TNT Run isn't a mod that you can install. It's a map (that you can build yourself, if you like) plus a mod that disables TNT explosions. In the [classic TNT Run video](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/119441/4163) they're playing on a server, so they're probably using one of the many Bukkit server plugins to disable TNT explosions.

If you want to play TNT Run, your best option is to run a local Bukkit server with an appropriate "no explosions" plugin.

Other "minigames" are going to be some combination of maps, mods, or both. I can't tell you how to install them without knowing what they are, but in general it will mean downloading a copy of the map and installing any necessary mods for the minigame to work right. Usually minigames are developed on servers, so the advice of setting up a Bukkit server will often apply to other minigames.

Comment: Or maybe playing on a public server that has TNT run?

Answer (score 0):

TNT Run [now seems to exist as a vanilla map using command blocks that you can download and play in Singleplayer](https://www.planetminecraft.com/project/tnt-run-5633701/)